# Nginx + Puma + Sidekiq web interface not showing css styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, sidekiq

I have an angularJS web app running in a Nginx server that sends request to a Rails API running in a Puma server. I have integrated Sidekiq 5.2.8 and everything works great but the Sidekiq web interface.

In my Nginx config file, I have a rule to pass request to the API. Please find the whole nginx.conf document:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    upstream api.development {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
        server unix:/tmp/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on; 
    
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # set client body size to 10M #
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    gzip  on;


    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        root   /Users/Rober/Projects/domain/dev/domain/app;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    

        # Proxy requests to the backoffice Rails API
        location /api {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_redirect off;
            rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://api.development;
        }

        # Rule to proxy the sidekiq web UI
        location /sidekiq {                  
             proxy_pass http://api.development;             
        }


        # Expire rules for static content
        # RCM: WPO
        # Images                                                   
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
            root    /Users/Rober/Projects/domain/dev/domain/app;
            expires 1w;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }  


        # This rule is the root cause of the problems with the sidekiq css
        # I have commented it for testing purposes
        # CSS and Javascript
        #location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        #        root  /Users/Rober/Projects/domain/dev/domain/app;
        #        expires 1w;
        #        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        #}      
        
        # I have replaced the previous location above for this as suggested by @Beena Shetty. 
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            add_header X-debug-message "Into the location css" always;
            if ($uri !~* "^/sidekiq/\w*(.*)+$") {
                add_header X-debug-message "Into the location css if" always;
                root  /Users/Rober/Projects/domain/dev/domain/app;
                expires 1w;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
            }
        }        


        # cache.appcache, your document html and data
        location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
            root   /Users/Rober/Projects/domain/dev/domain/app;
                expires -1;
        }
    }
    
    include servers/*;
}
```

In Rails:
routes:

```
    require 'sidekiq/web'
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
```

I have included next rule in Nginx config file and now when I request http://localhost/sidekiq I can see the web interface and navigate, but still cannot see the styles.

```
location /sidekiq {                     
                proxy_pass http://api.development;
        }
```

See screenshot.[image]

The dev tools shows that when I load sideqik is trying to get bootstrap.css and some other css and javascript in http://localhost/sidekiq/stylesheets/bootstrap.css

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**
I have found out the root cause of the problem in my nginx.conf. I have next rule that set a cache expiration time for performance purposes. If I comment this code, everything works. But how can I have both things living together?

## CSS and Javascript

```
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            root  /Users/Rober/Projects/domain/dev/domain/app;
            expires 1w;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:** Just in case the problem comes from another point, I have included my whole nginx conf.
Now, with the provided config, the expiration rules in my web app are still working, but the css in the sidekiq webapp do not.
I have included two headers as debug. One when the server is accessing the location rule and the second when the server is accessing inside the if condition. When I request my home page with `localhost` and I check the request for my own css, such as app.css, I can see the header `X-debug-message: Into the location css if`, which is right.
If I request sidekiq with localhost/sidekiq I still get 404 error for css, let´s say http://localhost/sidekiq/stylesheets/bootstrap.css and I can see the header `X-debug-message: Into the location css`.

Current conclusions:

1. As soon as I include the location ~* .(?:css|js)$ rule, sidekiq css stops working. Even if the rule is empty, like:

   ```
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {     
        }
   ```
2. As soon as I delete or comment the whole rule, the sidekiq css works perfectly, but unfortunately this is not compatible with the expires rules that we need to include for performance purposes.

Comment: Css and javascript are saved in the application but it is searching inside sidekiq path. You have  to configure in Nginx to  redirect to http://localhost/stylesheets/bootstrap.css

Comment: Please see my update that I just wrote while you commented.

Comment: Try putting the code location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ above the location /sidekiq block.

Comment: Sorry, not working. I´m getting GET http://localhost/sidekiq/stylesheets/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is this url working i.e localhost/stylesheets/bootstrap.css

Comment: Well, I´m confused. Answering your question, in localhost/stylesheets/bootstrap.css I cannot find any stylesheet. I have my web app stylesheets in http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css. However, I understood that sidekiq provide its own css and js inside his gem. So, I should not point to my web app css. Right?

Comment: @Rober are you sure you are approaching things the right way? Configuring Nginx to get some basic css working seems like something is very, very wrong.........unfortunately I have very little knowledge on webservers to be able to help.

Comment: @Rober SIdekiq gem has its own css and js whose path is /sidekiq/stylesheets/ and sidekiq/javascript.

Comment: @Rober Try the code which I have added in the answer section.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955460/8271939 ?

Comment: I´m first trying to make it work in development env. In my rails config development.rb I had none of the mentioned configs. Just in case I included the suggested config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx but unfortunately nothing happened. In any case, in the nginx config file in mentioned post, there is not a rule like location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {}. As soon as you include it, it stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
     if ($uri !~* "^/sidekiq/\w*(.*)+$"){
            root  /Users/Rober/Projects/domain/dev/yanpy/app;
            expires 1w;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand what you try to do, but unfortunately still not working. I have updated the post with the whole config file and much more details. Please let me know how can I help you.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a fix for this, so I hacked it with the following method: I copied `sidekiq`'s assets to the `public` folder and it started working ( since they're referenced by the UI ).

```
|- images
|-- favicon.io
|-- logo.png
|-- status.png

|- javascripts
|-- application.js
|-- dashboard.js

|- stylesheets
|-- application.css
|-- application-rtl.css
|-- application-dark.css
|-- application-rtl.min.css
|-- bootstrap.css
```

Mainly, these files: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/web/assets

Comment: Thanks for your approach. I will try it, although I´m already using my own bootstrap.css file in my web app, and not sure how will work. In any case, I think this is a bug or at least a limitation is sidekiq. I mean, unless stated the opposite, as soon as you add the location rule for css, which maybe required for many different reasons, sidekiq web ui prevent working, right?

Comment: Correct; I'm not sure why it's not possible to fix in NGINX. And btw, if you copy the files to `public/sidekiq/..` they won't affect your website's assets, they would work in parallel